# jQuery - animate + scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm using this code to scroll to a DIV with a #number. The problem is that it scrolls to the top of it.

I need it to offset by 100 or so pixels. My current code does it, but window.scrollBy(0,-100); has a rapid movement and the animation looks ugly. Is there a way to animate the window.scrollBy(0,-100);???? Thanks in advance!!!

Her is the current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>

    var number = 0;
    var goSign = "";

    function goToByScroll(id){              
            //$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+id).offset().top},'slow','swing',function(){window.scrollBy(0,-100);}); 
    }

    function iterate(goSign)
    {                               
        if(goSign == "next")
        {           

            if(number < 12 && number >= 0)
            {
                goToByScroll(++number);
            }
            //alert(number);
        }
        else if(goSign == "previous")
        {
            if(number <= 12 && number >= 1)
            {
                goToByScroll(--number);
            }               
            //alert(number);
        }
    }

    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div style = "position:fixed; top:90px;right:200px;width:200px;height:50px">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="iterate('next')">Next</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="iterate('previous')">Previous</a>
</div>


<div style="width:600px">
    <div id="1">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="3">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="4">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="5">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="6">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="7">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="8">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="9">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="10">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="11">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="12">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+id).offset().top - 100},'slow','swing');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brDNU/

Comment: That is what the code does already. I need to offset it a little bit so you could see a piece of previous paragraph.